# Use Visual Studio Test Runner with custom build configuration

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, buildconfiguration

I'd like to use a custom build configuration (e.g. `UnitTest`) for running C# unit-tests within the Visual Studio test runner.

From the command line, I can run `dotnet test --configuration UnitTest`, but this does not allow me to *easily* run individual tests or debug into tests like I can with the test runner.

Does anyone know of a way to specify a build configuration for the VS Test Runner to use?

I have tried setting the solution build configuration in Visual Studio, but it seems this is ignored by the Test Runner.

[Using specific Visual Studio Project Build configuration for running unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331570/using-specific-visual-studio-project-build-configuration-for-running-unit-tests) relates to running tests on Team City and I can't find anyone else with the same problem.

Many thanks!